# FeedDialog using WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Store App in which I need to publish some message and image on user's profile. Using WebAuthenticationBroker I have allowed the user to login and it returns a token but then I want to open Feed Dialog. How can I achieve this? I have read publishing text on facebook is possible using WebAuthenticationBroker but could not found any code for it. So my question is which url I need to pass in WebAuthenticationBroker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass facebook publish dialog url to webauthenticationbroker for this. Code should be something like this.

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer"))
```

Here app_id is your app id registered on facebook. Hope this helps.